# Using output of expression in bash string slicing

Tags: bash, string, command-substitution

I want to extract a substring of a filename from a path of unknown length. I can do these two parts separately, but I wonder if there is a way to combine the two without a temporary variable?

```
INPUT_PATH=/path/to/subfolder/file_17.txt 
# I would like to extract "17", the filname will always be 'file_XX.txt'
# The subfolder name is variable length 

TMP=$(basename ${INPUT_PATH})
FILE_NUMBER=${TMP:5:2}
echo ${FILE_NUMBER} # This works as expected
```

I tried `${$(basename $INPUT_PATH):5:2}` but this gives a bad substitution error. Is there any trick to doing this?

Comment: in two steps with [string manipulation](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PYCbHnpE4_wJ:https://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-scripting-10-string-manapluation-examples): *var=${var##\*_}; var=${var%.\*};* beginners friendly: *var=$(echo $var | cut -d_ -f2 | cut -d. -f1);* **or** *var=$(echo $var | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | tail -n1);* (i prefer *echo* before `<<<` *here-strings* because it is working in "any" shell)

Comment: `${${INPUT_PATH##*/}:5:2}` would work in Zsh... Though I didn't get the version with `$()` to work.

Comment: @ilkkachu, in `zsh`, you'd use `${${INPUT_PATH:t}[6,7]}` or to extract the first number in the tail: `${(MS)${INPUT_PATH:t}##<->}`. If you had to use command substitution, `${"$(basename -- $INPUT_PATH)":5:2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a different approach to the problem and providing a one-line solution using only `bash` functionality:

```
$ cat demo.sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_PATH=/path/to/subfolder/file_17.txt

FILE_NUMBER=${INPUT_PATH:((${#INPUT_PATH} -6)):2}
echo ${FILE_NUMBER}
$

$./demo.sh
17
```

A simpler approach would to count back from the end of the string, i.e.

```
FILE_NUMBER=${INPUT_PATH: -6:2}
```

Obviously, this solution depends on the string variable ending with "##XXXX" where "##" are the two digits of interest and "XXXX" are the last 4 characters of the string.

Comment: `${INPUT_PATH: -6:2}` should do. You don't need the parenthesis for the substraction, the limits of the substring slice are already taken in arithmetic context. But you also don't need `${#INPUT_PATH}`, as negative numbers count from the end by default. You _do_ need a space between the colon and the minus sign though, otherwise it's confused for the `${var:-default value}` expansion.

Comment: @ilkkachu Sure, you can do it that way and it is simpler. I just choose to demonstrate that arithmetic evaluation works within parameter expansion.  Updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: It was the space that was missing! I'd tried `FILE_NUMBER=${INPUT_PATH:-6:2}` but not  `FILE_NUMBER=${INPUT_PATH: -6:2}`

Comment: @David258:  You could also use `${INPUT_PATH:(-6):2}`.  It’s one more character (a pair of parentheses rather than a space), but some people might find it clearer and/or more intuitive.  The key thing is that the **`-`** doesn’t appear right after the (first) **`:`**.  Therefore, the space in fpmurphy’s long answer is unnecessary; you can do ``${INPUT_PATH:((${#INPUT_PATH}-6)):2}`` (with no space).  It turns out that the `((`…`))` is also unnecessary; you can shorten the long answer to ``${INPUT_PATH:${#INPUT_PATH}-6:2}``.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using bash, you could use regex matching:

```bsh
if [[ $input =~ ([[:digit:]]+)\.txt$ ]]; then
    file_num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use FILE_NUMBER instead of TMP:

```bsh
FILE_NUMBER=$(basename ${INPUT_PATH})
FILE_NUMBER=${FILE_NUMBER:5:2}
```

Also, using parameter expansion is faster than calling basename:

```bsh
FILE_NUMBER=${INPUT_PATH##*/}
FILE_NUMBER=${FILE_NUMBER:5:2}
```

You can use sed to do everyting on a single line, but it's slower and less readable:

```
FILE_NUMBER=$(sed 's|.*/||;s/.....\(..\).*/\1/' <<<"$INPUT_PATH")
```

Comment: `sed` is also less reliable. It really does not do well with paths that contain newlines... At least GNU `sed` knows `-z`, though.

Comment: Why is FILE_NUMBER easier to use than TMP?  It is not a reserved variable in `bash`.

Comment: @fpmurphy: It's the easiest way to solve the problem without a temporary variable.

Comment: @choroba  But you use FILE_NUMBER as a temporary variable!

Comment: @fpmurphy: No, I use the output variable to hold a temporary value ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `${var:offset:length}` syntax is [**parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). The output of a command substitution is not a parameter (aka variable).

The "trick" is to assign the output of the command substitution to a variable.

Or, do all the work in the command substitution:

```bsh
num=$( echo "$INPUT_PATH" | rev | cut -d. -f2 | cut -d_ -f1 | rev )
```

---

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: A minor nitpick. Each command in the pipeline is executed in its own subshell, which is a separate process, except possibly the last element of a pipeline. Not very efficient.

Comment: maybe not efficient but works for file_1.txt and file_999.txt

Comment: @alecxs.  True, but the OP specified exactly two digits.

Answer (score 0):

For those using `zsh` instead of `bash`:

- 6th to 7th characters of the *tail* (part returned by `basename`) of a path:

  ```
  num=${${a_path:t}[6,7]}
  ```

  (`$var:t` from `csh` to get the `t`ail)

  You could also do `num=${"$(basename -- "$a_path")":5:2}` using that `ksh93` `${var:offset:length}` operator recently added to `zsh` for compatibility. The command substitution has to be quoted so it doesn't yield an array so that the `:5:2` selects a range of characters instead of a range of array items. However using command substitution and executing `basename` would end up being less efficient and less reliable than using `zsh`'s builtin `:t` operator.
- first sequence of digits in the *tail*:

  ```
  num=${(MS)${a_path:t}##<->}
  ```

  `${var##pattern}` is the ksh operator that strips the longest leading string matching the `pattern` from `$var`. With the `M` flag, the `M`atched part is returned instead of being stripped, and `S` looks for `S`ubstrings, not just at the start. And `<->` matches any sequence of digits (`<x-y>` with unspecified bounds).
- sequence of digit after a `_` in the *tail*:

  ```
  num=${${a_path:t}/(#m)*_(<->)*/$match[1]}
  ```

  (needs `extendedglob`; beware it returns the full tail if there's no `_digits` in `$a_path`).

  Or:

  ```
  [[ $a_path:t =~ '_([[:digit:]]+)' ]] && num=$match[1]
  ```